# How to write a logic of powershell to check if a environment PATH variable is install (or set)?

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, cmd

I am going to write a powershell script to automatically publish my python code with pyinstaller.
In order to run this script more flexible, I want to check if this local PC already install pyinstaller.
It's similar the syntax in cmd

```
where /q choco
if !errorlevel! neq 0
```

and I hope I can write this logic in powershell, is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nearly do the same in PowerShell. Just expand `where` to `where.exe` to make sure, it is not used as the `Where-Object` cmdlet. You can query the exit code with `$LASTEXITCODE`:

```bsh
where.exe /q choco
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    # choco is not available
}
```